# How do I add currency formatting to this table w/ sumtr + datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have this table where I am using sumtr for the table footer, and displaying all the data within datatables.
I need to display all the values as currency however.

I cannot change the values post sumtr because it won't be able to calculate the strings.

the Code for the tables here:

```
<table id="invoice_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

@foreach (var item1 in Model.Date1)
        {
            try
            {
                string par = item1.theMoney.Value.ToString().Replace("-", "");

        <tr>
            <td>Cash</td>
            <td class="sum">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.theCount)</td>
            <td class="sum">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => par)</td>
        </tr>

    }
    catch { }
}
@foreach (var item2 in Model.Date2)
        {
            try
            {
                string par = item2.theMoney.Value.ToString().Replace("-", "");
        <tr>
            <td>Cheque</td>
            <td class="sum">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.theCount)</td>
            <td class="sum">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => par)</td>
        </tr>
            }
            catch { }
        }
@foreach (var item3 in Model.Date3)
{
    try
    {
        string par = item3.theMoney.Value.ToString().Replace("-", "");
            <tr>
                <td>Online</td>
                <td class="sum">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item3.theCount)</td>
                <td class="sum">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => par)</td>
            </tr>
    }
    catch { }
}
        @foreach (var item4 in Model.Date4)
        {
            try
            {
                string par = item4.theMoney.Value.ToString().Replace("-", "");
                <tr>
                    <td>PAP</td>
                    <td class="sum">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item4.theCount)</td>
                    <td class="sum">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => par)</td>
                </tr>
            }
            catch { }
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="summary">
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td class="first">?</td>
            <td class="second">?</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {

            $('#invoice_table').sumtr();
            $('#invoice_table .summary').sumtrRatio('.first', '.second');


            $('#invoice_table').DataTable({
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

What the table looks like: 
Need it to be in proper currency format ("C"): $94,029

[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I did it

```
        $('#invoice_table').sumtr({
            onComplete: function(e){
                e.find('.summary').each(function(index) {
                    var second = $(this).find('.second').data('sumtr');
                    $(this).find('.second').html('$' + (second).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
                });
            }
        });
```